# Modified Orthonormal Procrustes Problem

Tags: matrices, global-optimization, norms, traces

In the general orthonormal Procrustes problem, we want to find an orthonormal matrix $C$ to minimize $\|Y-XC\|_F^2$, where $Y$ is a known $n\times q$ matrix, $X$ is a known $n \times m$ matrix, and $C$ is an $m \times q$ matrix. We have $m<q$ (so $C$ is a wide matrix) and $CC^T=I_{m \times m}$. This problem has an analytic solution and we have $C = UV^T$, where $X^TY = UDV^T$ is the SVD.

Now, I want to minimize another objective function with the same constraint. I want to minimize $\|YC^T-X\|_F^2$ subject to $CC^T=I_{m \times m}$ (all the dimensions are the same as before).

Does this problem have a unique solution? If yes, can we compute that solution analytically? Is there a numerical procedure to solve this problem?

Comment: If $C$ is square and orthogonal, $||Y-XC||_F=||(Y-XC)C^T||_F=||YC^T-X||_F$, since the Frobenius norm is invariant by orthogonal transformation. Am I missing something?

Comment: Well, as mentioned above, $C$ is not square. It is $m \times q$ with $m<q$.

Comment: You're right, sorry, my bad. :/

Answer (score 1):

Sorry if I'm wrong, but I think that the general Orthogonal Procrustes Problem is the second one (not the first) because the condition is that the factor is column-wise orthonormal and this is verified by **C'**, not for **C** that is row-wise orthonormal.

The solution for the second problem is the orthogonal polar factor of **Y'X**:
**Y'X** = **USV'** -> **C'** = **UV'**

Francisco Arteaga